# PS1 setting on macOS using Modulo

Tags: unix, bash, macos, command-line

I'm trying to set up my `PS1` setting in my `.bash_profile` for my company laptop (Touchbar Mac) and noticed special characters like `\u` and `\w` were being used literally. I tried using the single and double quotes, nothing worked.

When I echoed the default setting, I found it was using modulos. `%n` for username and `%d` for working directory. I've googled it a few times and haven't been able to find any resources.

Anyone seen this before? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you're using Zsh, not Bash. Zsh is the default on later versions of macOS

Comment: It would take some work for `zsh` to (try to) use `.bash_profile`, though.

Comment: You guys were correct. I created and then populated a `.zshrc` file and everything worked.